# Не могу сверстать layout в android, что не так,?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-linearlayout

Через RexyclerView вывожу элементы списка с следующим макетом каждого элемента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="currency"
            type="com.pet.moneyconvertor.room.CurrencyEntity" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@{currency.name}"
            android:textSize="14pt"
            tools:text="Рубль"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCharCode"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{currency.charCode}"
            android:textSize="14pt"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            tools:text="RUB"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Результат который я получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на скрине, правый TextView прижат к левому TextView. А левый не заполнил собой все пустое пространство.

При чем дизайнер показывает нормально, как мне и нужно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте код onCreateViewHolder 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), **parent, false**)

Comment: было просто LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).
Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Вы используете Weight для распределения элементов макета. Чтобы указывать в какой пропорции будут размещены ваши TextView нужно у каждого элемента указывать это поле:

```
android:layout_weight="..."
```

в вашем случае данное поле стоит только у первого текстового поля. Так же стоит учитывать что этот параметр начинает "работать" только когда у виджета ширина (высота) установлена на 0:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

чтобы ваши виджеты не переполнили родительский макет стоит установить в нем сумму весов [WeightSum](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout#attr_android:weightSum):

```
android:weightSum="..."
```

В вашем случае можно поставить например сумму весов 4, где на наименование валюты будет выделено 3:

```
android:layout_weight="3"
```

а на код валюты 1:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

### UPDATE

попробовал я полностью проэмулировать вашу ситуацию. Сделал адаптер для списка и загрузил в него демо данные, используя при этом разметку вашего элемента:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:text="Рубль"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14pt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCharCode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="RUB"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14pt" />

</LinearLayout>
```

вот что показывает дизайнер в студии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот что показывает эмулятор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть и второй вариант разметки:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:text="Рубль"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14pt"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCharCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RUB"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14pt"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

это то что регулирует распределение элементов:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85" />
```

вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я очень сомневаюсь что dataBinding ломает всю разметку)

Comment: Я раньше тоже так думал. Пока не столкнулся с этой задачей.
Ваш совет не помог.

Comment: я понял, сейчас попробую второй вариант добавить

Comment: @KonstantinKuritsyn, посмотрите пожалуйста обновленный ответ, вы это хотите видеть на вашем экране?

Comment: да это. Спасибо за помощь!
Причина была в том, что я не все параметры указал в createViewHolder методе.(

Comment: да, там тоже могут быть проблемы, рад что у вас все получилось :)

Comment: ни смотря на то, что дело было не совсем в верстке, огромное спасибо!)
Кстати вариант с ConstraintLayout, как по мне даже интересней.

Comment: да, сейчас все на этот вид макетов переходят) решил добавить, и не прогадал)